# В C++ при наследовании определяется доступность только открытых элементов родителя?

Tags: наследование, ооп, c++

Прочитав несколько статей по этому поводу не могу сказать, что точно все понял.
 Такая конструкция

```
class Child : private Parent ...
```

сделает все публичные элементы родителя приватными у наследника? 
И так же, если там указать `public` или `protected`, то это влияет только на публичные родительские элементы или нет?

Comment: Сейчас еще получше покурил оф. туториал. Понял так: все наследуемые элементы, чей уровень доступа больше указанного при наследовании, изменяют его на указанный. Те, у которых меньше уровень, оставляют его неизменным. Так?

Comment: Так. Видите, и сами разобрались.

Comment: Спасибо за подтверждение :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. private (закрытый, внутренний член класса) — обращения к члену допускаются только из методов того класса, в котором этот член определён. Любые наследники класса уже не смогут получить доступ к этому члену. **Наследование по типу private делает все члены родительского класса (в том числе public и protected) private-членами класса-наследника (С++)**
2. protected (защищённый, внутренний член иерархии классов) — обращения к члену допускаются из методов того класса, в котором этот член определён, а также из любых методов его классов-наследников. **Наследование по типу protected делает все public-члены родительского класса protected-членами класса-наследника (С++)**;
3. public (открытый член класса) — обращения к члену допускаются из любого кода. **Наследование по типу public не меняет модификаторов родительского класса (С++)**;

---

Таким образом, ответ на ваш вопрос: `class Child : private Parent` - да, такое наследование сделает все публичные элементы родителя приватными у наследника.

Comment: Вы чего написали то -??? Сами перечитайте - что приватное наследование запрещает доступ из дочернего ко всем членам родительского??? И ниже сами себе противоречите что доступ у дочернего все таки будет, но приватным

Comment: И правда, я не очень хорошо сформулировал пункт 1 (изначально предполагалось, что там будет стоять что-то в духе: "...запрещает доступ из объекта дочернего класса ко всем членам родительского класса", - но затем решил абстрагироваться от объектов, но, как видимо, подправил не везде. В итоге, накосячил :) ). Спасибо за более-менее адекватную критику, подправил.

Comment: Ответ у вас хороший после правки ) просто недавно тут вопрос был "зачем нужно приват наследование если все члены родительского класса становятся недоступными в дочернем" так что вторая такая формулировка за две недели заставляет задуматься что  где-то в вики или учебнике накосячили и вводят в заблуждение массы :) вот ссылка  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483247/private-наследование/483248#483248

Comment: Вы довольно точно подметили на счет [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) :) (сейчас я подправил там соответствующую часть статьи, чтобы в дальнейшем она не вводила в заблуждение людей). На самом деле данное определение довольно давно прочитал на википедии и решил воспользоваться им здесь (сначала хотел написать отсебятину, но потом подумал и решил, что лучше воспользоваться устоявшимся определением с вики)