# Private наследование

Tags: c++, ооп

Для чего нужно наследование с описателем доступа private, если все поля базового класса станут недоступными?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 15):

Именно для того, чтобы все члены базового класса не были доступны снаружи (были доступны только изнутри класса, или друзьям класса).

Наследование мало чем отличается от аггрегации, и
`class A : private B { ... };` аналогично
`class A { private: B b; };`.

Одна в отличие от `private: B b;`, при наследовании функции `B` можно вызывать как члены своего класса, т.е. не `b.f()`, а просто `f()`.

Также можно унаследоваться от абстрактного класса, и переопределить его методы, не показывая все эти детали наружу, например:

```
struct Callback { virtual void done() = 0; };

void run(Callback* b);

class Cls : private Callback {
public:
  void some() {
    run(this);
  }
private:
  void done() override { ... }
};
```

Comment: А зачем такое вообще может пригодится? Ну кроме потому что можно?

Comment: @Flownee Чтоб приватные члены базового класса остались в производном так же скрытыми от остальных, чтоб не получились публичные члены класса (что всегда подозрительно)

Comment: в примере `Callback` не должен был зваться `Base`?

Comment: @Flowneee, это наследование функционала без отношения «is», т.е. после такого наследования класс наследник не может быть преобразован к родителю.

Comment: @Flowneee, как и почти все в ООП для того, чтобы автору было приятно писать, а остальным (при исправлении багов) было сложнее *быстро и точно понять*, а почему же вся эта фигня не работает.

Answer (score 11):

Приватное наследование — это по существу композиция, выраженная немного по-другому. При композиции у вас вложенный объект доступен по своему имени, но не виден снаружи. При приватном наследовании вложенный объект «влит» в `*this`.

Вообще, роль наследования — выражать отношение Is-A между классами. То есть, выражать наследование интерфейса, при этом наследование имплементации есть техническая деталь. А приватное наследование именно это и не может,
при приватном наследовании наследуется именно имплементация, но не интерфейс.

Поэтому практически всегда вместо приватного наследования стоит предпочесть именно композицию: она выражает ту же идею, но явно.

Comment: Читал ваш ответ, и в голову пришла мысль - возможно использование приватного наследования будет эффективнее по производительности чем явное использование агрегации (меньше потребления памяти) + меньше инструкций на вызов сокрытых методов

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Хм :)

Answer (score 3):

При приватном наследовании `public` и `protected` члены базового класса будут вполне доступны, как приватные члены в производном классе.